# Web API Call in Standalone React App Generating a CORS error

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs

I have a project that is only a frontend, built with React, in which I am trying to make a call to an external API when an LI is clicked. Here is my code for one of my components. I took out the actual url from this snippet because it is very long, but the call works when using Postman.

```
getPlayerStats(name) {
    fetch(url)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.resultSets.rowSet
        })
}
```

This produces this error in my browser console: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Any help on this issue? Most of the info I've read has suggestions for things to do on the backend, but my project does not have a backend. Thanks!

Comment: One question, in your browser are you using an URL like "http://localhost..." or you are using "file://..."

Comment: browser address bar says "file://..."

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are loading your app using `file://`, the browser will not use the `CORS` policies with `file://`

You must use a local server like `Apache` or `Nginx` to serve your frontend app and load again with `localhost`, in that case, the request to the API will have the header `Origin` with value and the server will accept it.

If you are developing frontend apps, it's not a good way to load with `file://`, use always a local web server.